# how to show progress when read any URL in android?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have one problem in url like"http://sample.com/test" that have large amout of xml data i am not able to show progress bar in mainUI.

Please do needful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **AsyncTask** ,background task **save the xml in local memory**.

```
                    int count;
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("http://sample.com/test");
                        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                        conection.connect();
                        // getting file length
                        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
                        // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
                        // Output stream to write file
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.pc.demo/temp.xml");
                        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                        long total = 0;
                        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                            total += count;
                            int progress = (int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile) ;
                            System.out.println("update---"+progress);
                            publishProgress(progress);
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }

                        // flushing output
                        output.flush();
                        // closing streams
                        output.close();
                        input.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                    }
```

onPostExecute

```
     File yourFile = new File("/data/data/com.pc.demo/temp.xml");
     InputStream input =  new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(yourFile), 8086);
```

onProgressUpdate

```
    setProgressPercent(progress[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override the onProgressUpdate() function of your AsyncTask, and use the publishProgress(Progress... values) in the doInBackgroud() to push your saving status to the progress then update it, here is my simple code, wish can help you.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]); //change this with your progress bar
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}